# How to use (-) symbol to leave spaces when making links through data retrieve from the database in php

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I want to make a sentence to a link (retrieve from the database)
but it take the %20 marks for the spaces.I want to get rid of this.Please help me.
I have tried everything but they didn't make sence.Please help me with this!
Thank you !

i want top get a clean url like this :

how-to-get-rid-of-the-20-from-my-url-when-extracting-a-query-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so we can be more helpful.

Comment: i removed them,Im thinking about str_replace .Do you think this is posible  ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @abishban Yes, this is possible. Follow the link provided by Pamblam for examples on how to use str_replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$link = str_replace(' ', '-', $sentence);
```